# Using columns from junction table in "where" clause in sequelize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to perform this query in sequelize models:

```
SELECT Cou.country_id,cou.country_name, Sta.state_id, Sta.state_name, Dis.district_id,
Dis.district_name,Cit.city_id, Cit.city_name,Loc.location_id,Loc.location_name,Sub_Loc.sub_location_id,Sub_Loc.sub_location_name,Prop.property_id,Prop.property_name,Prop.hp_builders_id,
Bud.builders_id,Bud.builders_name
FROM hp_country Cou
INNER JOIN hp_state Sta ON Cou.country_id = Sta.hp_country_id
INNER JOIN hp_district Dis ON Sta.state_id = Dis.hp_state_id
INNER JOIN hp_city Cit ON Dis.district_id = Cit.hp_district_id
INNER JOIN hp_location Loc ON Cit.city_id = Loc.hp_city_id
INNER JOIN hp_sub_location Sub_Loc ON Loc.location_id = Sub_Loc.hp_location_id
INNER JOIN hp_property Prop ON Sub_Loc.sub_location_id=Prop.hp_sub_location_id
LEFT JOIN hp_builders Bud ON Prop.hp_builders_id=Bud.builders_id
where (Cou.country_status=1 AND Sta.state_status=1 AND Cou.country_id=1)
AND (Dis.district_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Cit.city_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Loc.location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Sub_Loc.sub_location_name LIKE '%ky%' OR Prop.property_name LIKE '%ky%')
```

My Sequelize code is unable to find the hp_districts.district_status column name .But i am getting hp_states.states_status column.so how can get these remaining table column names in where clause and how to perform and/or clause from out of where conditions

```
 hp_country.findAll({
            attributes: ['country_id', 'country_name'],
            where: {
                //main AND condition
                $and: [
                    //first joint condition
                    {
                        $and: [
                            { country_status: 1 },
                            { country_id: 1 },
          Sequelize.col("hp_states.state_status = 1")
                 ,
                Sequelize.col("hp_districts.district_status = 1")
                        ]

                    }
                ]
            },

            include: [
                {
                    model: hp_state,
                    attributes: ['state_id', 'state_name'],
                    required:true,
                    where:{
                        state_status:1
                    },
                    include:[{
                        model: hp_district,
                        attributes: ['district_id', 'district_name'],
                        where:{
                            district_status:1
                        },
                        required:true,
                        include:[{
                            model: hp_city,
                            where:{
                                city_status:1
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            ]
        })
```

Comment: In future, please do not re-ask the same question repeatedly; whether through a new account, or your own (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976673/using-columns-from-junction-table-in-where-clause-in-sequelize?noredirect=1). See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/getting-attention-for-unanswered-questions.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap column name in main where with `$` symbol, that allows to do query to columns in include

```
hp_country.findAll({
        attributes: ['country_id', 'country_name'],
        where: {
            country_status: 1,
            country_id: 1,
            '$States.state_status$': 1
        },
        include: [
            {
                model: hp_state,
                as: 'States',
                ...
```

Comment: is it $nested table.column name $  supports for  sequelize@v2.0.2 .i am getting hp_state column . my problem is to access hp_districts.district_status  column in where clause

Comment: still getting `unknown column` for some reason